# Why does the last element reflect the number of non-negative solutions?

Tags: python, bottom-up

Please excuse my naivete as I don't have much programming experience. While googling something for an unrelated question, I stumbled upon this:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-number-of-solutions-of-a-linear-equation-of-n-variables/

I completely understand the first (extremely inefficient) bit of code. But the second:

```
def countSol(coeff, n, rhs): 

    # Create and initialize a table 
    # to store results of subproblems 
    dp = [0 for i in range(rhs + 1)] 
    dp[0] = 1

    # Fill table in bottom up manner 
    for i in range(n): 
        for j in range(coeff[i], rhs + 1): 
            dp[j] += dp[j - coeff[i]] 

    return dp[rhs]
```

confuses me. My question being: *why does this second program count the number of non-negative integer solutions?*

I have written out several examples, including the one given in the article, and I understand that it does indeed do this. And I understand how it is populating the list. But I don't understand exactly *why this works.*

Please excuse what must be, to some, an ignorant question. But I would quite like to understand the logic, as I think it rather clever that such a little snip-it is able able to answer a question as general as "How many non negative integer solutions exist" (for some general equation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This algorithms is pretty cool and demonstrates the power of looking for a solution from a different perspective.

Let's take a example: 3x + 2y + z = 6, where LHS is the left hand side and RHS is the right hand side.

`dp[k]` will keep track of the number of unique ways to arrive at a RHS value of `k` by substituting non-negative integer values for LHS variables.

The `i` loop iterates over the variables in the LHS.  The algorithm begins with setting all the variables to zero.  So, the only possible `k` value is zero, hence

```
k        0   1   2   3   4   5   6 
dp[k] =  1   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

For `i = 0`, we will update `dp` to reflect what happens if `x` is 1 or 2.  We don't care about x > 2 because the solutions are all non-negative and 3x would be too big. The `j` loop is responsible for updating `dp` and `dp[k]` gets incremented by `dp[k - 3]` because we can arrive at RHS value `k` by adding one copy of the coefficient `3` to `k-3`.  The result is

```
k        0   1   2   3   4   5   6 
dp[k] =  1   0   0   1   0   0   1
```

Now the algorithm continues with `i = 1`, updating `dp` to reflect all possible RHS values where x is 0, 1, or 2 and y is 0, 1, 2, or 3.  This time the `j` loop increments `dp[k]` by `dp[k-2]` because we can arrive at RHS value `k` by adding one copy of the coefficient `2` to `k-2`, resulting in

```
k        0   1   2   3   4   5   6 
dp[k] =  1   0   1   1   1   1   2
```

Finally, the algorithm incorporates z = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, or 6, resulting in

```
k        0   1   2   3   4   5   6 
dp[k] =  1   1   2   3   4   5   7
```

In addition to computing the answer in pseudo-polynomial time, `dp` encodes the answer for every RHS <= the input right hand side.

Comment: Thank you for such a lucid explanation.

Comment: @just_getting_started - you are welcome! And welcome to stack overflow.  When you receive a complete answer to a question, accept it.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers for details.  Voting on questions/answers and accepting answers helps everyone by highlighting relevant content over the background noise.